# use of boolean in DataObjectMethodAttribute declaration?

Tags: c#

What is use of Bool parameter in

[System.ComponentModel.DataObjectMethodAttribute(DataObjectMethodType.Select, True)]
Method name()

Comment: -1: Please look at the documentation first, and perhaps accept some answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Type:** `System.Boolean`
**Description:** `true` to indicate the method that the attribute is applied to is the default method of the data object for the specified `methodType`; otherwise, `false`.

This is from the **[MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ad99k3d.aspx)**.  I recommend reading it `:P`

Answer (score 0):

From here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ad99k3d.aspx

```
isDefaultType:
    System.Boolean
    true to indicate the method that the attribute is applied to is the default method of the data object for the specified methodType; otherwise, false.
```

Answer (score 0):

MSDN states that the parameter isDefault determines if the specified DataObjectMethodType has that method as default action.

```
methodType
One of the DataObjectMethodType values that describes the data operation the method performs.
isDefault
true to indicate the method that the attribute is applied to is the default method of the data object for the specified methodType; otherwise, false.
```